# mysql query select yesterday, today, and tomorrow

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm working on a project where I must select from database all entries which dates are yesterday, today, and tomorrow. 
The dates are stored in the database as timestamp.

I have this PHP codes so far

```
$hour = 12;
$today = strtotime("$hour:00:00");
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', $today);
$tomorrow = strtotime('+2 day', $today);
$today = get_date($today,"timestamp");

$result = $DB->query("SELECT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "expiry WHERE expiry_date BETWEEN $yesterday AND $tomorrow");
```

It's not working. please help.

Comment: What format are your dates stored in in your database? `strtotime` returns a Unix timestamp. You may need to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(expiry_date)`. Are you getting any error message? You haven't really given us enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $tomorrow = strtotime('+1 day', $today);
```

and th sql change to this

```
   BETWEEN '".$yesterday."' AND '".$tomorrow."'
```

and make sure that

```
   `" . DB_PREFIX . "expiry`
```

is not like that

```
  `" . DB_PREFIX . "_expiry`
                    ^---------------did have this or something else like -
```

Comment: thank you so much. it finally work. wow i've been searching for a solution to this since dec 25 :(